# Always array is empty while using gson to parse

Tags: java, android, gson

This is my json response,

```
[
  {
    "album": "http://MyMp3Song.Com",
    "artist": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakka",
    "index": "#",
    "path": "/storage/sdcard1/Download/04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com).mp3",
    "title": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com)",
    "duration": 369424,
    "id": 32004
  },
  {
    "album": "http://MyMp3Song.Com",
    "artist": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakka",
    "index": "#",
    "path": "/storage/sdcard1/Download/04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com).mp3",
    "title": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com)",
    "duration": 369424,
    "id": 32004
  }
]
```

i used the following code to create the above json

```
public static class SaveFavourites extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String json5 = gson.toJson(favouriteTracks.getFavourite());
                prefsEditor.putString("favouriteTracks", json5);
            prefsEditor.commit();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Im retrieving parsing the above created response as follows,

```
 gson.fromJson(json5, Favourite.class);
```

But when I parse it is always an empty array.

How can i be able to parse it using gson?

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing an array of `Favourite`, so you should provide a suitable type. For instance `List<Favourite>`:

```
List<Favourite> list = gson.fromJson(json5, new TypeToken<List<Favourite>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns an empty array

Comment: @J.Doe I tested it myself, and it works fine. You probably have an error somewhere else then.

Comment: I have tried it. The data is persisting only when the the app is resumed after stop. Once if its destroyed, the data is not being persisted and the array is hence empty :(

Answer (score 0):

your json response is jsonArray( **since it is starting with a "["** ) but you are receiving it as json, thats where the problem is.
you should probably use toJsonArray or something to remove it. if still error persists. ask me about it.

Comment: How can I be able to sort that out?

Comment: All that I need is to store favourite songs in a json array and saved it in shared preference. Access it later on

Comment: well, shared preferences are recommended to store very less data like some int or boolean value, so i'd not recommend that. use sqllite database instead.